# Update to latest Indy TCP library version

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy10

I'm using DELPHI XE2 since E/2011. I checked now the implemented INDY Lib shipped with my compiler, and found gsIdVersion = '10.5.8.0';

If I want to upgrade to the latest INDY version, I use  [Indy download link](http://indy.fulgan.com/)

here I found [LATEST INDY ZIP FILE](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/). The date of the file is from today, the revision is is less then my installed indy version ID. bevore doing any further action, Can some help me and solve my version number confusion

Comment: You may have a look at http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/svn.en.aspx

Comment: And don't mix Revision Number and Version Number

Comment: To upgrade to the most recent version of Indy (now Indy 10) follow the [`Installation Instructions`](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) with the current [`development snapshot`](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.EN.aspx). But to keep track with the updates is better to use [`subversion`](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/svn.en.aspx) system. Anyway, currently is Indy in version 10.5.9.0.

Comment: BTW your download link shows a pdf "Getting the latest Indy 10 snapshot using Tortoise SVN" - did you read it? ;o)

Comment: @TLama, technically, the latest version as of tonight is 10.5.9.4910 (10.5.9 SVN rev 4910), and it is easier to download nightly snapshots from the [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/) than from SVN directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the subversion repo, the latest revision for Indy 10 is r4910. The ZIP file that you link to is named Indy10_4910.zip. So that is as up-to-date as you can be.

The way to check something like this is to look at the source control repo yourself. The Indy website has a source control repo gateway page here: http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/Download/svn.EN.aspx

Update: If what @mjn says is true then the ZIP file may be out of date. I would always use svn to pull off the latest version.

Comment: There was a problem with the Atozed site recently which caused the ZIP archive to contain an older version despite having the correct number in its name. Subversion is the safest way to get the current release.

Comment: Fulgan has been having problems lately getting their automated scripts to put the correct SVN rev numbers in Indy's resource and package files (hopefully that was finally fixed the other day), but the ZIP filenames have usually been accurate. The current rev is 4911, so it is likely that Fulgan's latest ZIP was simply created before 4911 was checked in. Check back again tomorrow night.

Comment: @Remy What's with the certificate on the svn repo? I get a cert error when I browse to it. Is it self-signed?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: AFAIK, it is a self-signed certificate, yes. It is safe to let the browser accept. Otherwise, use an SVN client app instead, such as TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @Remy The SVN client complains as well. You really should not be using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am not an AToZed employee and did not set up the AToZed servers, so I have no control over that. AToZed controls that, so take it up with them. I am just an Indy developer who uses their servers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in fact, this is [documented on the Indy website](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/svn.en.aspx): "The SVN server currently uses a self-signed security certificate. You may be prompted with a certificate warning. Please accept the certificate."

Comment: **** My Report on latest update issues: ***** 1)the file IdTCPConnection.pas is missing in the ZIP file, results in compile error : DCC Fataler Fehler] IdDsnSASLListEditorFormVCL.pas(62): F1026 Datei nicht gefunden: 'IdTCPConnection.dcu'; 2)If you complie the *.dpk files as mentioned on the instruction on the indy project Web site, you need to set the File search path for every project to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Indy10_4910\Lib\System (this is my example)

Comment: add 1)  location inside ZIP file found :   C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Indy10_4910\Lib\Core

Comment: **** final report **** could install newest Indy lib with DELPHI XE2, current version String is now 10.5.9.4910 ; I need to add C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Indy10_4910\buildXE2 as a library search path to all my indy project; this path I used as output path compiling the INDY project dkp file