# DELPHI Compiler Path settings after INDY 10 upgrade

Tags: delphi, indy

I already asked how to upgrade to the latest Indy TCP TP components version ( [GET INDY COMPONENTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424582/update-to-latest-indy-tcp-library-versionhttp://)  )  and Installed Indy 10 with DELPHI XE 2 now.  For all the Indy projects I defined an outfolder in the project options section of DELPHI XE2, here I found later all the the ***.bpl files*** and all the **-DCU#s files** I need now in order to compile my application using the new INDY components to add this output folder as a library search path in these projects.

I found at my XE2 installation a path/folder  with *.dcu files for x32, x64, release and debug mode (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\lib\win64\release).

Do I need now all the INDY *.dcu I have created also in these different flavours compiled, how to set the path for all project to use the new *.dcu from my folder ?

Should I copy all my dcu's to these many sub folders ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not overwrite the .dcu files that are part of the Delphi installation. What's more, I would not recommend that you do anything with the .dcu files that you used to build these .bpl files.

What you should do is to include the Indy source files, the .pas files, in your project. Personally I prefer to avoid using a search path to achieve that and instead simply add all the necessary .pas files to the project. But you may prefer to use the search path option.

But the main point is that since this project is supplied in source form it is best to compile the source yourself, as part of your project. That makes it much easier for you, whilst debugging, to step through the Indy code. There's no need to have separate DCU files for release and debug. It makes the build process simpler, only one thing to build. It makes it easier if your source code targets multiple Delphi compiler versions.

Comment: There is no need to include the actual source files in a project if they have already been compiled.  Simply point the project's search paths at the folder(s) containing the compiled files. You can step through Indy source code whether you use .dcus are not, just compile Indy with debug info turned on (unless you are compiling the app with runtime packages enabled, that is).

Comment: @Remy What happens when the next developer checks the project out? How do they get the files compiled. That's why I put everything in the project. That way I've got a repeatable build process. Your approach makes the build process more complex, needlessly so. With your approach you now have to build two things instead of one thing.

Comment: @Remy I do find your stance odd. Do you really prefer using DCUs in your build to using source files? Is that the way you work?

Comment: To be honest, I don't use Delphi all that much, outside of Indy. I use C++Builder instead for the majority of my work. But I do work with Delphi source code all the time, when incorporating Indy and other third-party libraries into my projects, or when answering questions in user forums, or debugging into the VCL, etc. So yes, when I do have to compile Delphi sources into my projects, I usually pre-compile the source code into packages first, except for a few exceptions, like FastMM.

Answer (score 2):

You should not replace the pre-installed Indy files with the updated compiled files (in case you need the originals in the future, such as for DataSnap projects).  Install the newer Indy into its own separate folder, then update the projects search paths to refer to that installation's output folder(s) instread of the pre-installed folder(s).